# Swift user online status updates but it repeats on cells that is not supposed to

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a chat app and I configured a function to check if a user is online. I'm able to see if another user is active or not, but, the issue I'm having is that if I scroll down (I'm using a UITableView) other users show as active and they are not. I placed the code inside the UITableViewCell class. Any suggestions as to what could be the problem are greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

**UITableViewCell**

```
func configureHomeFeedCell(member: Member) {
    profileImage.loadImage(with: member.imageURL)
    profileName.text = "\(member.name)" + ", " + "\(member.age)"
    
    checkUserOnlineStatus(with: member.documentId) { _ in }
    
}

func checkUserOnlineStatus(with userId: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
    let query = USERS_COLLECTION.document(userId).collection(IS_ONLINE)
    query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("ERROR..\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            snapshot?.documents.forEach({ diff in
                let isOnline = diff.get(USER_IS_ONLINE) as? Bool
                self.onlineViewStatus.backgroundColor = isOnline == true ? .green : .red
                completion(isOnline!)
            })}}
        query.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            snapshot?.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                let isOnline = diff.document.get(USER_IS_ONLINE) as? Bool
                if (diff.type == .modified) {
                    self.onlineViewStatus.backgroundColor = isOnline == true ? .green : .red
                    completion(isOnline!)
                }}}
}
```

** cellForRowAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let hCell = homeFeedTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeFeedCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeFeedCell
        
        if !members.isEmpty {
            hCell.configureHomeFeedCell(member: members[indexPath.row])
        }
        
        hCell.selectionStyle = .none
        hCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        return hCell
    }
```

**Updated Solution**

**Service Class**

**This function is to update the user's presence when online or not and it's called inside SceneDelegate**

```
static func isUserOnline(bool: Bool) {
    guard let currentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
     
    if !currentUID.isEmpty {
      let dictionary = [USER_IS_ONLINE: bool as Any,
             USER_LASTEST_ONLINE: Date().timeIntervalSince1970 as Any] 
       
      USERS_COLLECTION.document(currentUID).getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let error = error {
          print("Error..\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
          if document?.exists == true {
            USERS_COLLECTION.document(currentUID).updateData(dictionary)
          } else {
            USERS_COLLECTION.document(currentUID).updateData(dictionary)
          }}}}}

**SceneDelegate**

func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    Service.isUserOnline(bool: false)
  }

  func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    Service.isUserOnline(bool: true)
  }

  func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    Service.isUserOnline(bool: false)
  }

  func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    Service.isUserOnline(bool: false)
  }


**This function is to monitor the user activity**
   
  static func checkUserOnlineStatus(with userId: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
    let query = USERS_COLLECTION.document(userId)
     
    query.getDocument { (document, error) in
      if let document = document, document.exists {
        let isOnline = document.get(USER_IS_ONLINE) as? Bool ?? false
        completion(isOnline)
      }
    }
    query.addSnapshotListener { (document, error) in
      if let document = document, document.exists {
        let isOnline = document.get(USER_IS_ONLINE) as? Bool ?? false
        completion(isOnline)
      }}}
```

**Calling the function inside the cell class**

```
func configureHomeFeedCell(member: Member) {

 Service.checkUserOnlineStatus(with: member.documentId) { isOnline in
      self.onlineViewStatus.backgroundColor = isOnline == true ? .green : .red
    } }
```

Comment: Update your question with your `cellForRowAt` data source method.

Comment: @HangarRash it has been updated.